# WPF ItemSource Not Working in XAML

Tags: wpf, binding, itemsource

I am writing a chess UI in WPF.

I have set the window datacontext in XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

I've defined the 'local' namespace as the namespace which holds the view model.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChessUI"
```

The view model has 1 property, a collection of chess pieces:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> ChessPieces { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
        :this(new ObservableCollection<ChessPiece>())
    {
    }

    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<ChessPiece> chessPieces)
    {
        this.ChessPieces = new ObservableCollection<ChessPiece>(chessPieces);
    }
}
```

I've tried to bind the `ChessPieces` to my `ChessBoard` (an ItemsControl) like this:

```
<Viewbox RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
    <ItemsControl Name="ChessBoard" ItemsSource="{Binding ChessPieces}">
        [...]
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

But it doesn't show the pieces at runtime.  However, if I uncomment the line below it works and I see all the pieces on the board.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel(this.GetStartingPositionChessPieces());
    //this.ChessBoard.ItemsSource = viewModel.ChessPieces;
}
```

Just to be clear:

With the binding set in the XAML:

[image: No Pieces!]

With the binding set in the code:

[image: With pieces!]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the XAML binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example,

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel(this.GetStartingPositionChessPieces());
    //this.ChessBoard.ItemsSource = viewModel.ChessPieces;
}
```

You are creating a viewModel but not using it. Perhaps if you assigned it as the window's DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, I believe you need to be instantiating the ViewModel and setting its DataContext when you instanciate the view..
Replace the line

```
var viewModel = new MainViewModel(this.GetStartingPositionChessPieces());
```

with

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(this.GetStartingPositionChessPieces());
```

Because

```
<Window.DataContext>
<local:MainViewModel />
```

Will just be using the zero argument constructor and not setting up your pieces).

Please note, DataContext, is not the same as ItemSource.

Hope this helps